# How to get or pass email variables into phtml

Tags: php, magento, email

Ok guys, wasted half a day on this and am giving up now.

Under my Your Account Has Been Activated email, I want to add to the email the Customer Unique Id code which is nothing more than the customer's initial + the Customer Id which I dynamically create using php.

Now I have the customer id   `{{var customer.getId()}}`   coming to the email and I have

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/customer_uniq_id.phtml'  customer_id_var='{{var customer.getId()}}' }}
```

which I am trying to pass customer_id_var with the Id to my customer_uniq_id.phtml

But it is not working and I have tried this:

```
echo Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('customer.ID')->getValue('plain');
```

and other codes but nothing.

Any clues on how to get the customer id when sending the email?

Cheers guys

Comment: Have you tried magic getter: `$this->getCustomerIdVar()`

Comment: It gives me {{var customer.getId()}} instead of the actual id...

Comment: How about using `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId()` in your phtml file

Comment: Thanks but session won't be active at the time it sends the email...

Answer (score 0):

Try $this->getData('order') as mentioned here: http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/06/customize-new-order-email-template-in-magento.html